# Master Page and Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, custom-masterpage, design-manager

I have the following line in my master page `<div id="searchBlock"></div>`.

On the Page Layout template, I want to insert the HTML code from Design Manager but i want it to be inserted within `<div id="searchBlock"></div>`

I tried the following but it didn't work:

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.getElementById('searchBlock').innerHTML = '<div data-name="SearchBox"><!--CS: Start Search Box Snippet--><!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SearchWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>--><!--MS:<SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart UseSiteCollectionSettings="true" EmitStyleReference="false" ShowQuerySuggestions="false" ChromeType="None" UseSharedSettings="true" TryInplaceQuery="false" ServerInitialRender="true" runat="server">--><!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth "><div WebPartID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" HasPers="true" id="WebPart" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex " OnlyForMePart="true" allowDelete="false" style=""><div componentid="ctl00_ctl03_csr" id="ctl00_ctl03_csr"><div id="SearchBox" name="Control"><div class="ms-srch-sb ms-srch-sb-border" id="ctl00_ctl03_csr_sboxdiv"><input type="text" value="Search..." maxlength="2048" title="Search..." id="ctl00_ctl03_csr_sbox" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" onkeypress="EnsureScriptFunc('Search.ClientControls.js', 'Srch.U', function() {if (Srch.U.isEnterKey(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) {$find('ctl00_ctl03_csr').search($get('ctl00_ctl03_csr_sbox').value);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event);}})" onkeydown="EnsureScriptFunc('Search.ClientControls.js', 'Srch.U', function() {var ctl = $find('ctl00_ctl03_csr');ctl.activateDefaultQuerySuggestionBehavior();})" onfocus="EnsureScriptFunc('Search.ClientControls.js', 'Srch.U', function() {var ctl = $find('ctl00_ctl03_csr');ctl.hidePrompt();ctl.setBorder(true);})" onblur="EnsureScriptFunc('Search.ClientControls.js', 'Srch.U', function() {var ctl = $find('ctl00_ctl03_csr'); if (ctl){ ctl.showPrompt(); ctl.setBorder(false);}})" class="ms-textSmall ms-srch-sb-prompt ms-helperText" /><a title="Search" role="button" class="ms-srch-sb-searchLink" id="ctl00_ctl03_csr_SearchLink" onclick="EnsureScriptFunc('Search.ClientControls.js', 'Srch.U', function() {$find('ctl00_ctl03_csr').search($get('ctl00_ctl03_csr_sbox').value);})" href="javascript: {}"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/searchresultui.png?rev=44#ThemeKey=searchresultui" class="ms-srch-sb-searchImg" id="searchImg" alt="Search" /></a></div></div></div><noscript><div id="ctl00_ctl03_noscript">It looks like your browser does not have JavaScript enabled. Please turn on JavaScript and try again.</div></noscript><div id="ctl00_ctl03"></div><div class="ms-clear"></div></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW--><!--ME:</SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart>--><!--CE: End Search Box Snippet--></div>';`

Answer (score 1):

You should insert the code snippet to page layout .html, SharePoint designer will help you for this, you can use other html editor also.

Demo:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats what I have now. But the search box is displayed at the very top (M365/SharePoint bar) and not where I want it displayed on the master page. I added responsive css which works well where i have the `searchBlock` but it doesnt work well with the search box displayed at the very top bar.